# Docker install in user home

Tags: linux, docker, docker-machine

I have access to `Grid5000` and would like to use `Docker` containers on it. Tutorial says, that users should install the tools in the user home. And add the user home to Path environment parameter.
How can I install it without use of `ap-get` command? My user isn't in `sudoers` group also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should download ot and add necessary permissions like above:

```
curl -sSL -O https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-1.10.3 > /home/docker && chmod +x /home/docker
```

After that you should add your home folder to `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no way to install the docker daemon without root permissions. You can have your user added to the docker group to control the docker daemon once it's installed without having to be root. https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#create-a-docker-group

You can also have docker-machine installed in your user home to control a docker daemon on a different machine without being root.

Comment: This tutorial says, it should be possible somehow: https://github.com/Spirals-Team/hadoop-benchmark _So users should install the two tools in the user home. And add the user home to Path environment parameter._

Comment: Sounds like they just mean the binaries. You can just download them (https://get.docker.com/builds/`uname -s`/`uname -m`/docker-latest & https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.6.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m`) and make them executable (chmod +x)

Comment: But it also requires `sudo` in `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: You can download them in your home folder. You don't need to place them in /usr/local/bin